# complex ternary expression in swift

Tags: swift

I came across the following function which I am having a problem understanding the syntax:

```
func countUniques<T: Comparable>(array: Array<T>) -> Int {
  let sorted = array.sort(<)
  **let initial: (T?, Int) = (.None, 0)**
  let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) { ($1, $0.0 == $1 ? $0.1 : $0.1 + 1) }
  return reduced.1
}
```

I understand ternary expression in swift, but this one I am totally confused:

```
let initial: (T?, Int) = (.None, 0)
```

can you please explain how it works?

Comment: That's not a ternary. That appears to just be a tuple of an optional T and and Int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a ternary expression.

It's a [tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/tuple-type-element) with optional [generic](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html) parameter that has two cases `.none` and `.some(_)`, `.none` means that there is nil.

So `let initial: (T?, Int) = (.none, 0)` means that you have two parameters in property where the first one is some `Comparable` and the second one is `Int`. The first is assigned `nil` and the second `0`.